# grouped by factor level in ggplot2()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a data frame with four three-level categorical variables: before_weight, after_weight, before_pain, and after_pain.

I'd like to make a bar plot featuring the proportion for each level of the variables. That my current code achieves.

The problem's the presentation of the data. I'd like the respective before and after bars to be grouped together, so that the bar representing the people that answered 1 in the before_weight variable is grouped next to the bar representing the people that answered 1 in the after_weight variable, and so forth for both the weight and pain variables.

I've been trying to use dplyr, mutate() with numerous ifelse() statements, to make a new variable pairing up the groups in question, but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

starting point (df):

```
df <- data.frame(before_weight=c(1,2,3,2,1),before_pain=c(2,2,1,3,1),after_weight=c(1,3,3,2,3),after_pain=c(1,1,2,3,1))
```

current code:

```
library(tidyr)
dflong <- gather(df, varname, score, before_weight:after_pain, factor_key=TRUE)
df$score<- as.factor(df$score)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dflong %>%
  group_by(varname) %>%
  count(score) %>%
  mutate(prop = 100*(n / sum(n)))  %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = varname, y = prop, fill = factor(score))) +  scale_fill_brewer() + geom_col(position = 'dodge', colour = 'black')
```

**UPDATE:**

I'd like proportions rather than counts, so I've attempted to tweak Nate's code. Since I'm using the question variable to group the data to get the proportions, I can't seem use gsub() to change the content of that variable. Instead I added question2 and passed it into facet_wrap(). It seems to work.:

```
df %>% gather("question", "val") %>% 
   count(question, val) %>%
   group_by(question) %>%
   mutate(percent = 100*(n / sum(n))) %>%
   mutate(time= factor(ifelse(grepl("before", question), "before", "after"), c("before", "after"))) %>%
   mutate(question2= ifelse(grepl("weight", question), "weight", "pain"))  %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=val, y=percent, fill = time)) + geom_col(position = "dodge") + facet_wrap(~question2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code make the visual comparisons you are after? One `ifelse` and a `gsub` will help make variables we can use for facetting and filling in `ggplot`.

```
df %>% gather("question", "val") %>% # go long
    mutate(time = factor(ifelse(grepl("before", question), "before", "after"),
                     c("before", "after")), # use factor with levels to control order
           question = gsub(".*_", "", question)) %>% # clean for facets
    ggplot(aes(x = val, fill = time)) + # use fill not color for whole bar
    geom_bar(position = "dodge") + # stacking is the default option
    facet_wrap(~question) # two panels
```

[image]

Comment: I think you could do the `mutate` in one step using `tidyr::separate(question, c("time", "question"), sep = "_")`